# Oracle SQL, Date and Time in GMT (UTC)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, timestamp, sysdate

This coding is giving the correct answer for SYSDATE

```
select round((SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60) from dual;

1662482430 (seconds)
```

I need to return the date / time in GMT/UTC.

I need help with the syntax.

Thanks, Pete

Comment: you want to return SYSDATE as UTC?  Question is not clear. Please show what type of result you are expecting as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SYSTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE then that value will be in your DB time zone, and you can then convert that to UTC with `at time zone`:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC'
```

and cast that back to a date:

```
cast(SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' as date)
```

and then use that in your calculation:

```
select round((cast(SYSTIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC' as date) - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60)
from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rQ5mouOI)